# Flutter: How to prevent my main widget from rotating and still keep track of it's orientation?

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to update a child widget's orientation with [Rotated Box](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwjBga3N4P3sAhVtG7kGHd4GDosQFjAAegQIAhAC&url=https%3A%2F%2Fapi.flutter.dev%2Fflutter%2Fwidgets%2FRotatedBox-class.html&usg=AOvVaw0fjaqssWD1SN7F1_zgJts-), based on my device orientation.

However, I have a constraint: I don't want my main UI app to rotate. I want to keep it always locked (like "portrait up"), but I still want to receive device orientation updates.

This is the partial solution I've found, using [native_device_orientation](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwiAxo_i1_3sAhXmIbkGHSoNCS0QFjAAegQIAxAC&url=https%3A%2F%2Fpub.dev%2Fpackages%2Fnative_device_orientation&usg=AOvVaw3cY0_CN9dulJtE1L8Fk2_s) package and     `SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([DeviceOrientation.portraitUp])`.

The problem is: it's super sensible to changes, so it is not suitable in a user experience perspective (as pointed by native_device_orientation author [here](https://github.com/rmtmckenzie/flutter_native_device_orientation/issues/10#issue-436815038)). Also, there is a 45 degree position that the sensor orientation goes frenzy, since the sensor is in the sweet spot between two orientations.

Is there another way or perspective to solve this problem?

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:native_device_orientation/native_device_orientation.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  int _counter = 0;

  void _incrementCounter() {
    setState(() {
      _counter++;
    });
  }

  int get_turns_based_on_orientation(NativeDeviceOrientation orientation) {
    switch(orientation) {
      _counter++;
      case NativeDeviceOrientation.portraitDown:
        return 2;
      case NativeDeviceOrientation.portraitUp:
        return 0;
      case NativeDeviceOrientation.landscapeLeft:
        return 1;
      case NativeDeviceOrientation.landscapeRight:
        return 3;
      case NativeDeviceOrientation.unknown:
        return 0;
    }
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([DeviceOrientation.portraitUp]);
  }
    
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: NativeDeviceOrientationReader(
        useSensor: true,
        builder: (context) {
          final orientation = NativeDeviceOrientationReader.orientation(context);
          return Center(
            child: Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: <Widget>[
                Text(
                  'You have pushed the button this many times:',
                ),
                RotatedBox(
                  quarterTurns: get_turns_based_on_orientation(orientation),
                  child: Text(
                    '$_counter',
                    style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline4,
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          );
        }
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: _incrementCounter,
        tooltip: 'Increment',
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
      ), // This trailing comma makes auto-formatting nicer for build methods.
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to have your orientation changed without any oscillation, you can try to reduce the sensibility with this as a workaround:

- Every time you receive a device orientation change, store the orientation received and the moment in time this change happened.
- Check after a specified amount of time if the orientation changed, if it has not changed in a while, re-render the screen based on this new stable orientation.
- Always render the screen based on the last stable orientation.

Adapting to your code it would be as follows:

```
[...]
//State Class properties
DateTime timeOfLastChange = DateTime.now();
NativeDeviceOrientation stableOrientation = NativeDeviceOrientation.portraitUp;
NativeDeviceOrientation currentOrientation = NativeDeviceOrientation.portraitUp;

[...]
builder: (context) {
          currentOrientation = NativeDeviceOrientationReader.orientation(context);
          timeOfLastChange = DateTime.now();
          Future.delayed(Duration(milliseconds: 500), () {
            if (DateTime
                .now()
                .difference(timeOfLastChange)
                .inMilliseconds > 500) {
              setState((){stableOrientation = currentOrientation;});
            }
          });
[...]
          quarterTurns: get_turns_based_on_orientation(stableOrientation),
[...]
}
```

Keep in mind that the `500` value is a constant that can be adjusted to increase or decrease the delay in orientation changes.

Comment: Hi, Naslausky. Worked like a charm. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I think you are not calling the `setPreferredOrientations` method in the correct place. You need to call it in your `initState()` and `dispose()` methods depend on your requirements. `Widget build()` method is the reason for the super sensible.

Comment: Hi Akif, thank you very much for your contribution. Indeed, the function should be called in .initState(...). However, it doesn't change the sensibility and the "sweet spot" effect at 45 degrees. I edited the question considering your warning. Thank you.